# When branch.<branchName>.remote and branch.<branchName>.merge values added by Git?

Tags: git

I want to know when does in config file `branch.<branchName>.remote` and `branch.<branchName>.merge` are filled by GIT the first time ? (Ignore user editing config files or giving direct commands to add remote etc)

Also, can just by usage of push and pull commands we change the above ?

**NOTE** : I am not interested in ways how we can change these values. Just in the specific case above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a specific *first time* for these, there are just commands that set or unset them.  One must therefore enumerate each command that could set them, and under what conditions:

- `git checkout`:

  - If `git checkout` is given the `--track` option when creating, or in order to create, a *new* branch name, `git checkout` will set both.
  - If `git checkout` is using the *DWIM mode* to create a branch, `git checkout` will set both when creating that branch.

    *DWIM* here stands for *Do What I Mean:* in this case you instruct `git checkout` to check out a branch name that does not exist, e.g., `git checkout develop` when you don't *have* a `develop`.  Instead of just immediately failing, `git checkout` scans through all your remote-tracking names, such as `origin/master`, `origin/develop`, `fred/master`, `fred/feature`, and so on.  If `git checkout` can find *exactly one* of these remote-tracking names that sufficiently matches the branch name you used, Git will *create* the branch, as if you had said `git checkout --track origin/develop`.

    Note that if you get *two* matches (both `origin/develop` and `fred/develop` exist, for instance), this DWIM mode fails, and you must say `git checkout --track origin/develop` if that's the one you meant.
  - All other cases of `git checkout` neither set nor unset the configuration items.  (Hence if your question was "when are they set for a newly created branch", the answer for `git checkout` is in the above cases.)
- `git branch`:

  - As with `git checkout` you can give it a `--track` option when creating a new branch.  There is no DWIM mode here.  If you do use `--track`, the two configuration settings are set based on the <start-point> argument.
  - You can also run `git branch --set-upstream-to` to set or change the current upstream setting of some existing branch.  If they were unset before, this changes them to set (to whatever value); but whether that's the *first* time they were set depends on whether you had them set even earlier and had unset them.
  - `git branch` has a deprecated `--set-upstream` option that means the same thing as `--set-upstream-to` but the order of arguments is "backwards" which results in a lot of user mistakes (which is why this is deprecated).
  - You can `git branch --unset-upstream` to *unset* both values.
- `git push`:

  - Most calls to `git push` don't touch the upstream setting.  Some will *use* it.  However, if you add the `-u` or `--set-upstream` flag to your `git push` command *and* the push succeeds, `git push` will immediately set both configuration items based on the push target remote and reference.
- And of course, `git config` and/or manual editing can change any of these, though you said you did not care about that.

Comment: Can git push pull make any changes in the above values ? Like auto updating it to newer remotes ?

Comment: Ah, yes, I left out `git push`: if you `git push -u`, and the `git push` succeeds, `git push` immediately has the effect of `git branch --set-upstream-to`. Back in the old days when `git push` was a script, it would have literally called `git branch` to do this (but back in those days it didn't have a `-u` option :-) ). I've added it to the list above.

Comment: This leaves us with git pull. :) Which I guess answer should be - no it cannot update `merge` value

Comment: Right, `git pull` doesn't ever alter these settings.

Comment: I have to say that I learned so much from your answers from past  and present on stackoverflow  about GIT and the extend you go to explain is amazing. Thanks a lot for your selfless effort .